# Nest js mongoose inject connection inside global interceptor

Tags: mongoose, dependency-injection, nestjs, nestjs-mongoose

I'm having some trouble injecting the mongoose Connection object inside a global interceptor in nest js. Here is my main module

```
imports: [
    ConfigModule.forRoot({
        isGlobal: true,
        load: [getConfiguration]
    }),
    TypeOrmModule.forRootAsync({
        imports: [ConfigModule],
        useFactory: (config: ConfigService) => config.get<TypeOrmModuleOptions>('postgres'),
        inject: [ConfigService]
    }),
    MongooseModule.forRootAsync({
        imports: [ConfigModule],
        useFactory: (config: ConfigService) => {
            const options = config.get('mongo');
            const uri = `mongodb://${options.host}:${options.port}/${options.database}`;
            return { uri };
        },
        inject: [ConfigService]
    }),
    OrderModule
],
controllers: [],
providers: [
    {
        provide: APP_INTERCEPTOR,
        useClass: TransactionInterceptor
    }
]
```

And here is the interceptor

```
@Injectable()
export class TransactionInterceptor implements NestInterceptor {
    constructor(
        private readonly pgConnection: PgConnection,
        private readonly mongoConnection: MongoConnection
    ) {}
}
```

For some reasone Nest can't resolve only the mongoose dependecy. The typeorm connetion gets injected just fine.
I also tried with an async provider like

```
@Injectable()
export class TransactionInterceptor implements NestInterceptor {
    constructor(
        private readonly pgConnection: PgConnection,
        private readonly mongoConnection: MongoConnection
    ) {}
```

What am I missing?
Thanks

Comment: What about using the `@InjectConnection()` decorator from `@nestjs//mongoose` and `@nestjs/typeorm` to inject the connections? You can still type them how you want, this just tells Nest specifically what the injection token is